# Out of range when splitting (Basic)

Tags: python

Im trying to read class objects from a text file and making it to a list, but I get out of range. I want to be able to add on activites in the text file and get them all printed when im calling for example: `activities.name`, without having to give out a specifik range of the list.

Text file:

```
Football 7-8
Eating 9-10
Running 11-12
reading 13-14
```

Code:

```py
class Activites:
    def __init__(self, name,startTime, endTime):
        self.name = name
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.endTime = endTime

def filee_():
    global activites
    activities = []
    f = open('text.txt', 'r').readlines()
    for i in f:
        time = i[2].split("-")
        activities.append(Activites(i[0], time[0], time[1]))  
    return activities
```

Comment: Try reading the error message. Where in the code does it tell you the problem occurred. What does it say is out of range? Can you line that up with the code in question, and figure out what is wrong?

Comment: activities.append(Activites(i[0], time[0], time[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range. I have tried to figure out whats wrong but cant

Comment: Try tracing through the logic a step at a time. When you do `for i in f:`, what are you expecting the `i` values to look like? Do they actually look like that? What are you expecting, say, `i[2]` to be? Does the actual result meet your expectation? What happens when you `.split('-')` that? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

you need to first split the `i` and take the index 1.

```
class Activites:
    def __init__(self, name,startTime, endTime ):
        self.name = name
        self.startTime = startTime
        self.endTime = endTime
def filee_():
    global activites
    activities = []
    f = open('text.txt', 'r').readlines()
    for i in f:
        print(i)
        i=i.split()
        time = i[1].split("-")
        activities.append(Activites(i[0], time[0], time[1]))  
    return activities
```

as your function **filee_()**  returns a list of objects of Activites.
you can use the below logic to iterate the list and get the name.

```
for item in filee_():
    print(item.name)
```

Comment: This doesn't completely solve the problem, because the `i[0]` passed to the constructor will be the first letter instead of the first word.

Comment: I do get error when im running the function and writing: print(activites.name)

Comment: replace `i=i.split()` with  `i=i.split('*')`, this might add extra trailing spaces to the i[0] and time[0] string you can add strip() before appending to the list.